# MATLAB - Building a matrix from the output of system commands in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, command, system

I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

I am trying to do the following.

Within a for loop, run 2 system commands and have the ouputs from those two commands make up all three elements of one row of a matrix for each iteration of the loop. I would then like to print the entire matrix to an excel file.

I tried this:

```
for i=1:3,
    command1 = ['fslmeants -i image1 -m example_' num2str(i) '.nii.gz' ]
    C(i,1) = evalc('system([command1])')
    command2 = ['fslstats example_' num2str(i) ' -V']
    C(i,2:3) = evalc('system ([command2])')
end
```

I received the following error message:

??? Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in ==> name_of_script at 8 C(i,1) = evalc('system ([command1])')

I then tried this

```
for i=1:3,
    command1 = ['fslmeants -i image1 -m example_' num2str(i) '.nii.gz' ]
    A = evalc('system([command1])')
    command2 = ['fslstats example_' num2str(i) ' -V']
    B = evalc('system ([command2)')
end
```

the output for system ([command1]) when I don't try to assign a matrix element to it is

```
A =

 0.302714

ans =

 0
```

the output for system ([command2]) when I don't try to assign matrix elements to it is

```
B =

 1413 19506.814453

ans =

 0
```

If I then type B(1,2) I get

```
ans =

 4
```

which gives me the second digit of the first number in B, not the second number (19506.814453) as I wanted.

I then checked if B was a character array as follows:

```
ischar B

ans =

   1
```

So I guess if I can find a way for matlab to recognise the output of system([command1]) and system ([command2]) as 3 elements of the same row for each iteration of the for loop I'd be sorted.

So ideally, the first row of the Matrix C would be

```
C(1,:) = [ 0.302714 1413 19506.814453 ]
```

and an extra row would be added with each iteration of the for loop.

Can anyone enlighten a lost soul?

Comment: `ischar B` is equivalent to `ischar('B')`, so you get 1 independently of content of variable B, even if you don't have such variable. Do `ischar(B)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output of a command, you should use the second output of system:

```
[~,output]=system('....');
```

To transform a string into a number or a matrix, use the function `str2num`.

```
str2num('123')
ans =
   123

str2num('1 2 3')
ans =
     [ 1     2     3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just collect the output of `system` call without using `evalc`?

```
[status, A] = system(command1);
[status, B] = system(command2);
```

if the output is a string of numbers separated by space you can use regexp with split option:

```
Bnum = str2double(regexp(B,' ','split'));
```

You can do the same for A (if command1 can return multiple numbers) or just convert string to number:

```
Anum = str2double(A);
```

Then you combine them to a single vector:

```
C(1,:) = [A, B];
```

Make sure though that both commands always return the same number of values.